# Python data structure for class varying by year

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class like this...

```
class person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.carData = ""        
        self.HouseData = ""
        #other assets
```

And am loading data like this...

```
for someone in person:
     someone.carData = runCarQuery()
     someone.HouseData = runHouseQuery()
     #load other assets
```

But the data varies by year, e.g. 2019, 2020 etc and I'm struggling to visualise an appropriate way to represent that in the data structure.  I know I could in theory do this...

```
class person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.carData2019 = ""        
        self.HouseData2019 = ""
        self.carData2020 = ""        
        self.HouseData2020 = ""
        #other assets
```

But it feels super clumsy so I'm hoping there's a way to point to a 2019 version of the carData object.  For example, a data model that supports something like...

```
for someone in person:
     someone.carData['2019'] = runCarQuery('2019')
     someone.carData['2020'] = runCarQuery('2020')
     someone.HouseData['2019'] = runHouseQuery('2019')
     someone.HouseData['2020'] = runHouseQuery('2020')
     #load other assets
```

I know that's not valid but am a bit lost on how to achieve the scenario in python.

Comment: Store it in a dictionary where keys are years and values are the data for that year.

Comment: "But the data varies by year, e.g. 2019, 2020 etc" what does that mean? Varies how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean:

```
# __init__
…
someone.carData = {}
someone.HouseData = {}
```

and then:

```
for someone in person:
    for year in (2019, 2020):
        someone.carData[year] = runCarQuery(year)
        someone.HouseData[year] = runHouseQuery(year)
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You can use @property https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

```
class person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name  
        self.HouseData = ""
        #other assets
    @property
    def carData(self):
        this_year = get_this_year()
        return  runCarQuery(this_year)

some_person = Person()

some_person.carData
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method that does the filtering for you:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name
      self.car_data = []
      self.house_data = []

   def car_by_year(self, year):
      return filter(lambda x: x['date'].year() == year, self.car_data)

   def house_by_year(self, year):
      return filter(lambda x: x['date'].year() == year, self.house_data)
```

You'll have to get some data structure in the `car_data` and `house_data` objects, perhaps a dictionary to store the year or date values.

```
p = Person('John')
p.car_data.append({'date': date(2018, 01, 01), 'model': 'Ford'})

for car in p.car_by_year(2018):
    print(car)
```